# Kotlin application stop building after adding analytics with message "Failed to transform play-services-measurement-api-21.5.0.aar"

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build.gradle

I tried adding google analytics in my application but since then build fail with the following error.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexPreprodDebug'.
    > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:preprodDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
       > Failed to transform play-services-measurement-api-21.5.1.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:21.5.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=28, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
          > Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: /Users/elpanda/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/5d7bcf57359759c2a79956972360f644/transformed/play-services-measurement-api-21.5.1-runtime.jar.
             > Error while dexing.
```

There is not much I changed, since I just added the analytics dependency. Still, here is an extract of my

```
    androidGradlePlugin = "7.4.0"
    firebase = "32.7.4"

    android-gradlePlugin = { group = "com.android.tools.build", name = "gradle", version.ref = "androidGradlePlugin" }

    firebase = { group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-bom", version.ref = "firebase" }
    crashlytics = { group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-crashlytics" }
    analytics = { group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-analytics" }
```

and an extract of my build.gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation(platform(libs.firebase))
    implementation(libs.analytics)
    implementation(libs.crashlytics)
}
```

I tried to invalidate cache and even remove gradle cache files manually but it didn't change anything. Does anyone have a solution for this issue ?

**EDIT**
I forgot to specify that I ran into this error only in debug builds. It works fine on release build where minify is enabled.